# Mongoose cannot connect to a single replica set at first connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I create a MongoDB replica set by using flag `--replSet rs`. the `rs.status()` works fine and the mongo-express can access that replica.

But when I try to use :

```
let options = {
  "replset": {
    "rs_name": "rs"
  }
}

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tasksDB', options);
```

to connect the mongodb. It throws out:

```
failed to connect to server [91891b77b79f:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 91891b77b79f 91891b77b79f:27017]'
```

If I remove the `options` to connect without replset option. It works fine.

I'd trid another way to connect the mongodb: `?replicaSet=rs`, still not working.